# Join a query into another query with column computation

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have three tables named issue_details, nature_payments, and rci_records. Now I have this query which joins this three tables.

```
SELECT  issue_details.issue_date AS Date,
        issue_details.check_no AS Check_No,
        payees.payee_name AS Name_payee,
        nature_payments.nature_payment AS Nature_of_Payment,
        issue_details.issue_amount AS Checks_issued,
        issue_details.nca_balance AS Nca_balance

FROM    
    issue_details

    INNER JOIN
       nature_payments ON
       issue_details.nature_id = nature_payments.nature_id
    INNER JOIN
       payees ON
       issue_details.payee_id = payees.payee_id
       ORDER BY Date Asc, Check_no ASC
```

On my column in Nca_balance, this is a computed differences of every issuances of check. But you may not know what really the process of how I got the difference but to make it simple, let's say that I have another query
that dynamically get also the difference of this nca_balance column. Here is the query:

```
SELECT r.*,
 (@tot := @tot - issue_amount) as bank_balance
 FROM (SELECT @tot := SUM(nca_amount) as nca_total FROM nca
    WHERE account_type = 'DBP-TRUST' AND 
    year(issue_date) = year('2015-01-11') AND
    month(issue_date) = month('2015-01-11')
  )
vars CROSS JOIN issue_details r
WHERE r.account_type = 'DBP-TRUST' AND
r.issue_date = '2015-01-11'
ORDER BY r.issue_date, r.check_no
```

I know it you may not get my point but I just want to replace the first query of the line

```
issue_details.nca_balance AS Nca_balance
```

with my own computation on my second query.

Please help me combine those two query into a single query. Thanks

Comment: FYI, you should remove the `sql-server` tag, as thats a tag for Microsoft SQL Server. I assume from the other tags that you want a MySQL answer.

Comment: yeah. do you have any idea ?

Comment: You should just be able to put the subquery in brackets and then treat it as if it were a table. Give it an alias and include the primary key of issue_details so you can join to it. I'm not a MySQL expert though. In the MSSQL world I would probably advise a table-valued function and using `CROSS APPLY`, but I don't know if there's an equivalent.

Comment: what do you mean by brackets? do you mean I should put it inside a parenthesis like '()' or '[ ]' ?